# How Enable Extended MQL When Reading From Freebase API

Tags: python, freebase, mql

Freebase contains a fair amount of documentation but lacks some specific examples of working code for many scenarios.

One of them is how to implement (in Python, using the Python Freebase library) a query using their eMQL service.  Which is an extended version of their MQL service.  The documentation states that you need to "set the envelope parameter to extended=true", but I cannot figure out how to actually do that (get the syntax right).

Here is the doc on the service I am trying to use: http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql_extensions/common#service

Here is an example of the code I am trying to get working using the extended service:

```
query = {
    "extended": True,
    "query": [{
        "id": "/en/settlers_of_catan",
        "/common/topic/weblink": [{
            "description": "Wikipedia",
            "url": None
        }]
    }]
}

result = freebase.sandbox.mqlread(query)
```

This fails, with the error, "Type /type/object does not have property extended".  Which I believe is telling me I am not actually setting the extended property and am trying to do it in the wrong place.

Comment: Removed tag google-app-engine. I presume you put it there because your app is running on App Engine - but it has no relevance to the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is simple - pass the envelope setting (in this case 'extended=true' to the mqlread function.

```
result = freebase.sandbox.mqlread(query, extended=True)
```

Of course note the capitalization of T in True.